# Rails4 // append strong_parameters with other params

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, mass-assignment

Let's say for the following actions' controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @post = Post.create(post_params)
    end

    private
        def post_params
          params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
        end

end
```

Is there a one-line way to do something like this when creating a record :

```
def create
    @post = Post.create(post_params, user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

What would be the clean way to do it ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` is an instance of ActionController::Parameters, which inherits from Hash. You can do anything with it that you might with any Hash:

```
@post = Post.create(post_params.merge user_id: current_user.id)
```

Or...

```
post_params[:user_id] = current_user.id
@post = Post.create(post_params)
```