# rails4 // has_many_through syntax when adding relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, syntax, associations, has-many

How would one pass parameters to a has_many association ?

Let's say we have categories and posts, associated with a join table, category_posts

```
category has_many category_posts
category_has_many posts, through category_posts
```

and reverse for the post (not the right syntax, to make it quick here)

Let's say we got this basic syntax for adding :

```
category.posts << post
```

The join table `category_posts` has a specific field that I'd like to fill when creating the above association.

I'm looking for a one-liner syntax to do it, if that'd ever be possible

Thanks for your advance experience feedback

(totally different, but this is what I mean by "one-liner syntax" [Rails4 // append strong_parameters with other params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517421/rails4-append-strong-parameters-with-other-params) : the kind of thing that tend to be done with many more lines of code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do it by adding to the `category_posts` relation directly, e.g.:

```
category.category_posts << CategoryPost.create(post: post, other_field: other_value)
```

or, slightly more condensed:

```
category.category_posts.create(post: post, other_field: other_value)
```